# Combining variables into resource paramter in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to use variables declared in the variable.tf file to compose some of the resource parameters, like for example its name.
I just got used to the new terraform variable syntax, after not using it for a couple of years, went from ${var.variablename} to var.variablename, which is much easier.
But, I used to use code like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network_rg" {
  name     = "rg-${var.location}"
  location = "West US"
}
```

This code still does what I need, but I would rather use the new syntax, but it seems that something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network_rg" {
  name     = "rg-var.location"
  location = "West US"
}
```

Does not work.
What is the equivalent of this in the new syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do that because with the interpolation syntax from the first example you tell terraform you want it to replace the placeholder variable name with the value that was assigned. The first example is valid syntax and there is no new syntax for that. The second will be a string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you showed in your example is already the simplest possible way to represent interpolating the value of a variable into a string template.

Your second example cannot work because Terraform has no way to know that you intend `var.location` to be a reference to a variable. The `${ .. }` template interpolation syntax *is* the way to tell Terraform that the result of a reference (or any other expression) should be inserted into the string dynamically.

Using `var.location` alone works directly after the `=` for an argument Terraform expects an expression. A reference like `var.location` is a valid expression, and a [string template](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#string-templates) is also a valid expression, but if you are using a string template then you must use the string template syntax for interpolation.